# Nested for loops while using os path python

Tags: python, os.walk

I am new to python and have been trying to populate a file with the names of a subdirectory and its files. However I am not allowed to nest a 2nd for loop when using os path.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("foobar", topdown=True):
    for parent in dirs, files:
        print(parent)
```

I tried to iterate through the parent then through the files nested loop style but then it gives me an error basically saying the list isn't populated. If I go line by line I files gets populated but i am unable iterate through two list.

To visualize filesystem:

```
foobar -> foo -> n number of files
       -> bar -> n number of files
```

I am trying to just print the subdirectories name with the name of the file

```
Ex: foo/n1
    foo/n2
    bar/n1
    bar/n2
```

Comment: You want to loop through the dirs and files without distinction? Try `for parent in dirs + files:` to concatenate the two `list`s and loop over the result. As is, you're making an anonymous tuple of the two, and printing the whole of each `list` at once. Otherwise, I'm not sure what your actual goal here is...

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, `root` will contain the full path of the current directory, and `files` will contain all the files in that directory. So just loop through the files, and join them with the root:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("foobar", topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file)
```